# Restore database using a bak file from another computer

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, database-restore, sql-server-2017

I have a SQL Server database on my PC. I backed up my database so now I have a `.bak` file.

I recently brought a new PC and want to move the database from my old PC to this PC.

I go to restore database & under source click on device. I then have the backup media type as file & then click Add. I browse to where my `.bak` file is. However when I browse to this directory no files show up which I don't understand why?

Can I not just copy over the backup file from my old PC to my new one? What am I missing?

Comment: do you see it if you change file types to All when you are searching for the .bak file?  The default is .bak, .trn, .log. but you can change it to all.

Comment: even when changed to all I still can't see the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it manually. First, find out where your new server keeps it's database (mdf) and log (ldf) files

```
SELECT name, physical_name FROM sys.master_files
```

Then, find out what the logical names of those files are in your backup

```
restore FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='c:\dir\file.bak'
```

Finally, use combine that info to do the restore:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DataBaseToCreate
    FROM DISK = 'c:\dir\file.bak' 
    WITH REPLACE, 
    MOVE 'DBLogicalName' TO  'C:\DB_DIR\DataBaseToCreate.mdf',
    MOVE 'LogLogicalName' TO  'C:\LOG_DIR\DatabaseToCreate.ldf'
```

Comment: should be a `,` at the end of the line of the first `MOVE` statement.

Comment: Yes, there should have been a comma there. I added it now.

Comment: There was one other remarkable thing I had to do: grant privileges to the `file.bak` file for the `NT Service/MSSQLSERVER` user. Without it, I kept having an "Access Denied" error message when using the `RESTORE`.